# Calculate huge number mod $p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to calculate $n\bmod p$ when $p$ is prime, and $n$ is an integer of form $a9999...$ where $a$ is digit $1$ to $9$. The number of digits $9$ that follow $a$ is huge (i.e. big enough to not fit memory of my PC).

Comment: Since $10^p\equiv 10\pmod{p}$, you can reduce it to more than $p+1$ digits.

Comment: By [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) $\bmod p\!:\ 10^{p-1}\equiv 1\Rightarrow (a\!+\!1)10^k\!-\!1\equiv (a\!+\!1)10^r\!-\!1\,$ for $\,r = k\bmod{\!p\!-\!1},\,$ for $\,p\neq 2,5\ \ $